# AutoIt3 find control handle not shown with AU3Info

Tags: autoit

Windows 10 SciTE 3.6.6

I have a window with a toolbar that contains a drop down that I am trying to get a value from but I am unable to find the window handle
The menu and item looks like this

[image]

I need to wait for a process to finish (but nothing is busy so waiting for a window does not seem to help).  I know for sure that the process is finished if this drop down contains a 1, it will be blank while the process is running.  I could also check if a sub menu item under Documents is enabled, but I have not been able to find a handle to the menu either.

When I drag the selector from AU3Info over the item outlines the main window and all values in the Control tab are blank

Comment: If you can't get any information with AU3Info, the window isn't a default windows - window (may be, it's created with Delphi or Java ...). In this case, it is unlikely to get access with AutoIt.

Comment: You can try using this instead: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/